# I'm trying to extend a class but exclude a certain property in the process

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have a class `Food` and I extended it to a class `OrderedItem` but I'm trying to extend it without the `num score` property. Is this possible?

```
Food {
      String imgUrl;
      String desc;
      String name;
      String waitTime;
      num score;
      int price;
      int pq;
      int quantity;
      bool favourited;
      List<Variation> variations;
      Variation selectedVar;
      String about;
      bool highlight;
    }
```

OrderedItem

```
class OrderedItem extends Food {
  Variation selectVar;

  OrderedItem(
      this.selectVar,
      super.imgUrl,
      super.desc,
      super.name,
      super.pq,
      super.waitTime,
      super.score, //I'm trying to remove this in the new class
      super.price,
      super.quantity,
      super.variations,
      super.about,
      super.favourited,
      {super.highlight = false});
}
```

Comment: how about passing hard-coded value like `super(score: 0);` or maybe you can follow some pattern like strategy

Comment: This would violate the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).   A derived class is expected to be a substitutable for the base type.  What would happen if you did `Food food = OrderedItem(...); print(food.score);`?  If `OrderedItem` must not have `score`, then refactor your class hierarchy so that `score` is not part of the base `Food` class or make `OrderedItem` use composition and not be directly related to `Food`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to "exclude" a property.

You should instead refactor your inheritance chain:
`Food` should not include a score property in the first place.
Remove the `score` property from food.
Introduce a new class `ScoredFood` which extends `Food` and adds the score property.
Now `OrderedItem` can extend `Food` without inheriting a score property.

Besides, reconsider whether you should be using inheritance or composition here.
Is an `OrderedItem` really a `Food`, or is a `Food` just part of an `OrderedItem` (and should thus be accessible as a `food` property of it)?